# Downloading LyX 2.1 Beta1, for Windows

Tags: lyx

I am considering downloading Beta Version 2.1 of LyX, I am currently using version 2.0.6 I have Three questions. The first is, how reliable is this beta version? Second, which files should I download If I am already using Version 2.0.6? Lastly, will I be able to use both versions side by side? I got the picture below from here ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta1.

[image]

Comment: While Lyx is on topic, in general beta software is borderline: it's hard to give solid answers on a somewhat 'moving' target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Beta 1 is reliable in my opinion. That said, I haven't heard much from Windows users. This could be because they have not had any problems but it's probably because not many are testing with beta.
2. You should be able to use them side-by-side.
3. You might want to wait. Beta 2 might be out [next week](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg181179.html) (althought note that this also depends on whether our Windows packager is available at this time. He's been very busy recently).
4. If there's not a [feature in LyX 2.1](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX21) that you specifically want to use and you are not prepared for the case where the install messes something up, then just wait for LyX 2.1. In fact, wait until 2.1.1 to minimize the risk.

Answer (score 3):

You must download LyX-210beta-Installer-1.exe file without .sig The other files are for Mcos-X and Linux. I don't know how stable is this beta version because i haven't tested it, but you can test it and if it doesn't work fine then you can uninstall it and install 2.0.6 version. The installer will say you if you can install both versions.